# Old animated movie, where ocean fishes are trying to survive the falling crates with poison

Tags: story-identification, movie, animated-series

Old, animated movie, where fish in the ocean fight versus poison crates dropped by "evil men."

One scene I remember is where two fishes eat the poison, and then they shrivel and die.

The story revolves around a group of ocean fishes where they suddenly find themselves threatened by pollution made by men. Specifically, I remember crates with skull signs on them falling on the bottom, cracking on one corner and spilling the black poison. Then some random fish started eating it and after they have eaten it, then shrivelled and died. There was a male and a female fish protagonist (maybe sturgeons, 10% sure). Some fish ate the poison later in the goal to save the protagonists.

Animated movie was old, depressing etc. Cannot remember more because I watched it around 2003.

Comment: Hi, welcomed to SF&F!  There isn't very much detail in this question.  Maybe you could review the [suggestions for a good question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if there are any other details you can remember?

Comment: Sorry but it is a very old memory and i dont have more info..... Dis is desperate 101...

Comment: Is there anything Sci-Fi or Fantasy about this other than a "talking animals" setup? https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5119/23243

Comment: @Bogdan still, please take a look at the guide linked above and [edit] in whatever it may trigger. At the very, very least, you probably remember when and where you watched that. It would also help if you could provide a bit more elements about these fish "fighting" (which seems to be the Science-Fiction part of that movie): did they have spears? Commandos? Were sharks teaming with octopi or something?

Comment: I did it... Sorry, if i bothered you.. Ty

Comment: You didn't bother anyone, no worries :) we just nudged you into giving a tad bit more info in order to increase the chances of a successful identification.

Comment: If it was whales instead of sturgeon if might have been [Samson and Sally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_%26_Sally)